Which PIE reconstruction is currently considered to best account for the attested data?
In particular is Pyysalo's reconstruction considered to be an improvement over older reconstructions like Brugmann's?
https://helda.helsinki.fi/items/1a4d765d-2158-4ad8-8d5e-b2b32356a188

The only person who thinks Pyysalo's system is an improvement over the traditional three-laryngeal system is Pyysalo himself. It's actually embarrassing for the University of Helsinki that that dissertation got accepted—it's a classic crank paper.

@Cairnarvon Oh, now I've gotta read this…

@Cairnarvon I would perhaps have put it a bit more diplomatically, but yeah. While I’ve heard lots of people express admiration for the attempt to think outside the box and take an unbiased look at the data, I’ve not come across anyone who actually thinks Pyysalo succeeded or came up with a system that adequately represents or explains the data. I wouldn’t necessarily go so far as to call it a crank paper, but there is most certainly a reason it hasn’t been successful or quoted much.

@JanusBahsJacquet To be clear, it's not that Pyysalo wants to challenge orthodoxy or the fact that he ultimately wasn't successful in itself that makes him a crank to me, it's the constant petty misrepresentation of the state of mainstream laryngeal theory, the pseudo-scientific notation salad, the vagueness about what problems "System PIE" solves that laryngeal theory doesn't, and the unwillingness to acknowledge any weaknesses in it while hailing it as revolutionary. Some of the general vibes might be due to a language barrier, but "crank" is very fair, I think.

Hmm. Yes, from an initial look, I do think he's substantially misrepresenting the laryngeal theory. Complaining that the sounds aren't produced in the larynx is a ridiculous objection, and he insists it's missing a correspondence set from the "Neogrammarian" model but never shows any evidence of what that correspondence set is.
